# Edit a mailto link in a pdf document

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to edit a "mailto" link in a pdf document. I write some text to my pdf document like the below:

```
emailaddress tel no: 000000 fax no: 0000000
```

An automatic mailto link is inserted but when you hover over the link is

```
emailaddresscomtelno:000000faxno:0000000
```

How can I edit so that just the email address is shown? I would like to keep the email, tel no and fax no on the same line.

Comment: If you edit the pdf document as an xml file, you could search the nodes of the file and check where are the fields you need to edit. Is that your case or you are using some specialised library?

Comment: I've been using SharpPDF to add the text etc. if that helps

Comment: "An automatic mailto link is inserted" - does that mean you do **not** add a real link into the PDF but rely on Acrobat's hyperlink recognition algorithm instead? (Which is switched off by prudent users, aware of the associated problems.)

Comment: It looks as if the hyperlink recognition in Acrobat/Reader is playing you a trick; a workaround would be to put the phone numbers on a separate line, or to create sufficient (whatever that means) distance between the eMail address and the phone numbers.